# How to differentiate between two type of user in firebase when signing up

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

In my app, I have two types of users, let say 'A' and 'B', I also have `auth.user().onCreate()` function in the background which is triggered every time a new user signs up, I need to figure out what type of user signs up 'A' or 'B', and then take the required action in the `onCreate()` function, so if it was 'A' do 'X' and if it was 'B' do 'Y' how can I do that?

Comment: How exactly are A and B users are different?

Comment: You cannot pass additional details to `onCreate()`. How do you check if user is of type A or B? One way would be to use a callable cloud function where you can pass user credentials and type of user and create user using admin SDK in the function.

Comment: won't I be able to send a flag and access it in onCreate() method ? that solves my problem

Comment: I have Customers and Users and wanna do an action based on the user type

Comment: No, you cannot add additional details in onCreate as mentioned earlier